# How do I replace text snippets with single words in comma seperated text column in Python Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, findandmodify

I would like to map the following values in a text column in a DataFrame like this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

I thought I could use a dictionary to map the text snippets to the single words. Here is my code that I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"col": ['i am hungry, you are pretty', 'i am hungry, you are pretty, i love flowers', 
              'i am hungry, i love flowers', 'i am hungry,choccies are nice']} 

replace = {'hungry': 'i am hungry', 
        'pretty': 'you are pretty',
        'flowers': 'i love flowers',
        'choccies':'choccies are nice'}

new = df.replace({"col": replace})
```

But I just get the original DataFrame back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the keys and the values of the dictionary, since replace method requires the dictionary to be in the form {"what to replace" : "replacement"}. You also need to specify the parameter **regex** as true, so that the replacement is carried out as a regex filtering. This should do it.

```
replace = { 'i am hungry'      : 'hungry', 
            'you are pretty'   :  'pretty',
            'i love flowers'   : 'flowers',
            'choccies are nice': 'choccies' }

df = df.replace({'col': replace}, regex = True)
```